# Create-react-app install stuck at post installation after "added 1350 packages in 2m"

Tags: installation, create-react-app

I have installed Nodejs then ran npx create-react-app firstapp

initial installation started and got stuck at post installation after "added 1350 packages in 2m".
I waited for an hour but not got any response.
Tried with multiple versions of Nodejs but no luck.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASDwU.png

Comment: Could you give us more info? Just with your issue and a picture of npx won't help us help you. Do you need to use ```npx create-react-app .```? If not, try using ```npx create-vite .``` and build a react project that way.

Comment: Thank you Amodh, I could able to create a react app through npx create-vite. I think both applications and coding will be same. create-react-app was getting stuck at this point.PS C:\Users\rajes\Desktop\React_Learning> npm init react-app myapp1 --verbose.
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   '-g'
npm verb logfile C:\Users\rajes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-14T02_44_17_682Z-debug-0.log
npm verb exit 0
npm info ok 

added 1350 packages in 2m
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? . Could not add full log due to size.